# Constructor addition to class without compliation fail

Tags: java, constructor

I was asked this question in one of the tests:

```
class A{
    int i;
    public A(int x){this.i = x;}
}

class B extends A{
    int j;
    public B(int x, int y){
        super(x);
        this.j = y;
    }
}
```

Given the following code, which of the constructors shown in the options can be added to class B without causing compilation to fail?

Options:

1. B() {}
2. B(int y){ j = y; }
3. B(int y) { super(y*2); j=y; }
4. B(int y) { i=y; j=y*2; }
5. B(int z) { this(z,z); }

What should be the answer?

I tried searching for it but want to know the reasoning behind the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried searching for it but want to know the reasoning behind the
> correct answer.

From [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) one can read:

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
> constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
> no-argument constructor of the superclass. **If the super class does not
> have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.**
> Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
> superclass, there is no problem.

Let us go through each option one by one:

1- `B() {}` No, because class `A` does not have no default constructor; 
2- `B(int y){ j = y; }`, No for the same reason a 1); 
3- `B(int y) { super(y*2); j=y; }`. Valid, this one explicitly invokes `super` with a valid constructor; 
4- `B(int y) { i=y; j=y*2; }` No, for the same reason as 1) and 2); 
5- `B(int z) { this(z,z); }.` Valid, this one calls the constructor :

```
 public B(int x, int y){
        super(x);
        this.j = y;
    }
```

which explicitly invokes `super` with a valid constructor.

If class A was instead :

```
class A{
    int i;
    public A(){}
    public A(int x){this.i = x;}
}
```

because now class A has explicitly the default constructor all options would be valid.